# Proof that $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to prove that $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$ without using any trigonometric identities?

To be specific, my calculus-book simply states that with an angle of $\pi/3$ on the unit-circle the points (0,0) and (1,0) are the vertices of an equilateral triangle with edge length 1. But how can one reach such conclusion?

Thanks!

Comment: Because any isosceles triangle with an angle 60 degree is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: You are stating that, but not proving it... furthermore, how do I even know the triangle is isosceles?

Comment: You need to first agree that $\pi \over 3$ is same as 60 degree, we will never come to any agreement if you don't accept this. Now you have a triangle of 30, 60, 90 and you flip it over the side opposite to the 60 degree angle and combining with the original triangle you get an isosceles triangle with a 60 degree angle.

Comment: If you don't want to use geometry or trig, how are you defining $\cos$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O=(0,0)$, $A=(1,0)$ and $P$ the point on the unit circle such that $\angle AOP=60°$. By construction you have $OA=OP=1$ so that $OAP$ is an isosceles triangle with base $AP$. The sum of the angles in $A$ and $P$ is $180°-60°=120°$ but as they are equal we find that $\angle PAO=\angle APO=\angle AOP=60°$ Hence $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Start out with an equilateral triangle of side length $a$.

Then drop a perpendicular from one of the vertices to the side opposite to that vertex. By symmetry you have split the triangle into two equal right triangles. Now consider one of these right triangles, one of the angles is $\pi/3$. Use the definition of cosine (as base/hypotenuse) to get the value of $\cos \pi/3$.

Comment: The question is: how can I be sure that the constructed triangle is an equilateral triangle in the first place?

Comment: @ImreVégh in my solution you start out with an equilateral triangle. I am not using the unit circle idea.